# Create a SSL key requiring client keys?

Tags: security, ssl, openssl

I'm hosting a service over HTTPS which I'd like to make fairly secure. I've heard that it's possible to create server keys which require specific client keys installed on a enduser's keyring. Is this possible, and how is it done using OpenSSL?

Answer (score 2):

The keys do not require other keys.  You make keys the standard way.

What you have to do is setup your web server software to require a certificate key be sent when the client makes the request.  You also must configure the server to point at a database of permitted keys, or permitted certificate authorities that you trust to issue certificates.

The exact details depend on the what server software you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a web server configuration, rather than anything specific to SSL.

Here's the Apache HOWTO on requiring client certificates:

[How can I force clients to authenticate using certificates?](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol)

So, you would create your own Certificate Authority, and then sign client certificates using that authority.  Apache will then be configured to accept those certificates.  OpenSSL has some [documentation here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt).  You should be able to find other references online, perhaps with more detail if that's required.